# bitmap file size vs byte[] size

Tags: c#, bitmap

`bmp.ToByteArray(ImageFormat.Bmp).Length 3145782 int` 
but file system shows as `2,25 MB (2.359.350 bytes) and Size on disk 2,25 MB (2.363.392 bytes)`

Why there is difference and how can I determine correct size of bitmap in byte[]
form?

```
    string appPath = Application.StartupPath;

    var bmp = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(appPath + "\\Images\\Penguins.bmp"));

    public static byte[] ToByteArray(this Image image, ImageFormat format)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, format);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Windows 7 / NTFS

Comment: What exact type are you talking about? And what is the format on disk?

Comment: Link to the `ToByteArray()` method documentation please.

Comment: Information added in question

Comment: What do you mean at correct size? What is context of your question? Every are correct because they have different context. Btw File has heading and maybe this is a difference betwen raw picture bytes and size on disk.

Comment: How did you get the file on disk? Please post the code that writes this to disk. Basically, try to post a complete example that demonstrates the difference. Most likely you will find that there's code outside of the posted code that creates the difference. For instance, a typical reason could be that you first load a 2.25MB jpeg from disk, and then resaves it to memory as a BMP, or as a JPG with a different quality factor, resulting in a new interpretation of the image and thus not the same exact bytes. Can you please explain the relationship between the byte array, the image, and the file?

Comment: var bmp = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(appPath + "\\Images\\Penguins.bmp"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that's because the file on disk doesn't contain an alpha channel, but in memory it does. On disk it's 3 bytes per pixel, but in memory it uses 4.

2359350*4/3 is 3145800 which is only slightly more than the value you see. I expect the slight difference is because on disk there is a header, but that's not actually part of the image.

Comment: Or perhaps (and maybe additionally) the format on disk is compressed and the in-memory one isn't?

Comment: True, but I was assuming it was a .bmp file on disk, which for 32bbp images is uncompressed. If that assumption is wrong then it could well be compression. I would expect a better compression ratio than 25% though, and the ratio between the numbers is quite a coincidence.

Comment: Now the OP has updated his question, I'm sure this (the missing alpha channel) is the answer.

Comment: I tried to convert Format32bppRgb still same size but when I do Format24bppRgb 2359350 int. so difference is not from alpha but bit depth. this ride me to the solution so I will accept as an answer, you maybe better add this to your answer for others who had same issue.

Comment: The difference between 32bpp and 24bpp is the 8 bit alpha channel.